# iOS:checkmark in did select row at index path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am doing iOS app related to tableview and it contains checkmark on the leftside of the table view .I have kept the image view not he prototype cell  and when the table view cell was selected one selected image appears and when again selected selected image should disappears.here is my code

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   
  *)indexPath

  {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


Contact_customCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[Contact_customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
   if([tableView  indexPathForSelectedRow])

           if([indexPath.row )
           {
               cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected"];
           }
            else
                       {
               cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected"];
           }
  }
```

please help .

Answer (score 0):

The image is being set based on `if([indexPath.row )` rather than the previous image setting of the cell.

If the user taps the first cell (index row zero) then the image will always be `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected"];`

If the user taps any other cell, the image will be `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected"];`

The code will need to get the current setting from the cell, then set the appropriate image.